# Why do openai gym return reward zero for terminal states?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, openai-gym

I've been experimenting with **Gym** (and RL) a lot lately and there is one specific behaviour of gym that has piqued my interest. Why is it that OpenAI Gym return reward 0 even when game is over? For e.g, in Breakout-v0, when all five lives are spent, env.step will return `done=True` and `reward=0`. Shouldn't we notify agent that such a state is unfavourable by returning a negative reinforcement/reward ?

Also, for every step on the environment (still Breakout-v0), it will return reward 0 if no bricks/blocks were destroyed at that time. So how will the an agent be able to differentiate between a *normal* action and *bad* action?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Reward does not matter when `done == True`. You should reset the environment by calling `env.reset()` when `done`.

Question 2: The rewards are the discounted sums over the entire lifetime of the trajectory.

Comment: Even if  `done == True`, we still add the experience to replay buffer, which may well be sampled for training the online network in the future. So how can reward not matter?

Comment: @NileshPS You shouldn't be adding experience to a replay buffer after the environment is done.

Comment: [DQN algorithm](https://reading-club.github.io/assets/posts/Playing_Atari_with_Deep_Reinforcement_Learning/algorithm.png)   If what you said is correct, then **y_j**  should be set unconditionally since **phi_(j + 1)** is never a terminal state.

Comment: @NileshPS here's an implementation https://github.com/jalexvig/berkeley_deep_rl/blob/master/hw3/dqn.py

Comment: @NileshPS `phi_{j+1}` can be terminal. But that should be the last tuple of experience added to the buffer. That can still have a nonzero reward `r_{j}`. You should never add a tuple to the buffer where both `phi_j` and `phi_{j+1}` are terminal

Comment: @Alex I took a look and it saves experience to the buffer even if `done=True`.  Lines 266 - 270

Comment: @NileshPS that's only one timestep since the environment is reset.

Comment: @Alex Got it. Thanks :-)  I am still not convinced about the second part of my question though.